# bind: ignoring out-of-zone-data error - syntax error?

Tags: bind

i'm not sure if I have a syntax error here. When checking one of my zone files using `/usr/local/Cellar/bind/9.16.9_1/sbin/named-checkzone watt14net.dyndns.org /var/named/22.168.192.zone` I get the following:

```
/var/named/22.168.192.zone:3: ignoring out-of-zone data (22.168.192.in-addr.arpa)
/var/named/22.168.192.zone:10: ignoring out-of-zone data (22.168.192.in-addr.arpa)
/var/named/22.168.192.zone:12: ignoring out-of-zone data (252.22.168.192.in-addr.arpa)
zone watt14net.dyndns.org/IN: has 0 SOA records
zone watt14net.dyndns.org/IN: has no NS records
zone watt14net.dyndns.org/IN: not loaded due to errors.
```

Here's a copy of my zone file:

```
$TTL 86400;

22.168.192.in-addr.arpa.    IN SOA  ns.watt14net.dyndns.org.    root.watt14net.dyndns.org. (
20000531      ; serial
2H            ; refresh
3M            ; retry
12W           ; expiry
1D )          ; minimum

22.168.192.in-addr.arpa.    IN NS   ns.watt14net.dyndns.org.

252.22.168.192.in-addr.arpa.    IN PTR  cloud.watt14net.dyndns.org.
```

I haven't set up `bind` for a long time. I'm not sure if the above syntax is still correct.

Any feedback is very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `named-checkzone` but I would guess from your usage that it's expecting to check the zone `watt14net.dyndns.org` and you've given it a reverse zone for `22.168.192.in-addr.arpa`. As a result it's telling you that the records are for the wrong zone

Comment: thanks! eventually the zones loaded fine after a reboot of the system.